# What causes the page jumping when applying formatting?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page, formatting, ie-11

SharePoint 2013 on premises, IE11, publishing site web page editing.

Applying formatting (anything like bold, colour, links) causes the page to immediately scroll (jump) the highlighted text to the foot of the page, so it's the last line in view. You have to scroll to regain position, and so the game goes on.

Happening most of the time. Pretty annoying. Any thoughts on what might be causing this, please?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the compatibility issue between IE11 and SharePoint 2013.

You can click F12 in the keyboard->Emulation tab, change the Document mode to 10, check if the issue exists.

Then go to Internet Options->Compatibility View Settings, add the SharePoint site to this list.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I've given this a go, one stage at a time and with restarts, but no joy I'm afraid. It's a problem across our business. Happens in Chrome too.